# How to copy all files of a certain prefix?

Tags: regular-expression, string

I have a bash script that reads file strings from an input text file and copies each file to a directory.

Some file strings are passed as `$file="*..."` where the file ends with `...` like `sim...` or `file...`, etc.

Each of the files it reads is stored in one directory. I need it to copy all files with suffix `...` and the certain prefix is has. Ex: If the string variable = `sim...`, copy all files with the prefix `sim`, etc.

I tried:

`if [[ $file = *"..." ]]; then cp -v $dir/$(dirname $file)* $tarpath; fi`

but that does not work. How do I return the file string's prefix, without `...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

```
$ file="sim..."
$ echo "${file%...}"
sim
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you! I knew the solution would probably be very simple. Still need to learn about hotkeys.